# iPhone master detail app how to use detail view to change the text value displayed in the corresponding cell in the master view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am brand new to iOS programming and am currently taking an iOS class at school. For a project that I am doing we have to write a basic master-detail application for iPhone. For my app, I am creating a simple to do list type of app. The name of each task is displayed in the master view, the name of the task can be changed in the detail view. I set up a save button that has an unwind segue delegate when pressed. When i press the button I segue back to the master view I cannot get the value of the corresponding cell to change in real time. I know that it the master view is getting the changed information back because the changed information doesn't get saved until control transfers back to the master view and it is getting saved. When I rerun the app, the new name is displayed instead of the default name.

here is the delegate for the unwind segue

```
- (IBAction) done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
// index for the cell in the master view table that was changed
NSIndexPath *changeIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

[self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:changeIndex];

// place the new dictionary entry created by the detail view in the location of the
// array where the old entry was located
_taskList[changeIndex.row] = self.ChangedEntry;

// store the change in the plist file
[_taskList writeToFile:self->documentPlistPath atomically:YES];
}
```

which calls this function, which appears to change the text for a cell in a table but I'm not sure

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = _taskList[indexPath.row][TASK_DATA_NAME];
return cell;
}
```

So yeah, I am just trying to figure out how to make the master view reflect changes made in the detail view without having to close the app and reopen it. Oh and I am using Xcode 5 and targeting iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, after you update your data model (`_taskList`) you need to refresh the table view by calling `reloadData` on it. This tells it to update all of the rows.

Comment: Hey thank you so much. That was one of the last things I needed to figure out for my project. Thanks.